# How to debug other assemblies in my Azure Project

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, azure

I have an Azure webrole in my VS project. I have assemblies in my webrole website which are throwing null reference errors so I need to debug these assemblies to discover where the problem is. 
The issue I am having is that once I run my Azure project in debug mode I cannot attach to w3wp.exe from another instance of visual studio (attach button grays out) as my Azure project is already debugging the process.

Is there some way to launch my Azure project without debugging it allowing me to attach to w3p.exe from the visual studio project that is throwing errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Ctrl+F5 (or Debug -> Start Without Debugging) to start your Azure project from VS. It will deploy your application in local emulator but will not attach the debugger. Then you can attach to w3wp.exe manually.

Answer (score 1):

There is.  You can use the [CSRun command line tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg433001.aspx) to run your webrole in the dev fabric without launching the debugger.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Intellitrace might work on the other instance of visual studio.